# How to apply function to each row of specified column of PySpark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark DataFrame consists of three columns, whose structure is as below.

```
In[1]: df.take(1)    
Out[1]:
[Row(angle_est=-0.006815859163590619, rwsep_est=0.00019571401752467945, cost_est=34.33651951754235)]
```

What I want to do is to retrieve each value of the first column (`angle_est`), and pass it as parameter `xMisallignment` to a defined function to set a particular property of a class object. The defined function is:

```
def setMisAllignment(self, xMisallignment):
    if np.abs(xMisallignment) > 0.8:
       warnings.warn('You might set misallignment angle too large.')
    self.MisAllignment = xMisallignment
```

I am trying to select the first column and convert it into rdd, and apply the above function to a map() function, but it seems it does not work, the `MisAllignment` did not change anyway.

```
df.select(df.angle_est).rdd.map(lambda row: model0.setMisAllignment(row))

In[2]: model0.MisAllignment
Out[2]: 0.00111511718224
```

Anyone has ideas to help me let that function work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register your function as spark UDF something similar to follows:

```
spark.udf.register("misallign", setMisAllignment)
```

You can get many examples of creating and registering UDF's in this test suite:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/test/java/test/org/apache/spark/sql/JavaUDFSuite.java

Hope it answers your question